# Separating each different Javascript property within object within array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been stumped with this for a while.  Basically, I have an array of objects (focusing on only the "00" object for now), and I want to group together the bestScore properties, like this:

..

User Group

apple

..

User Group

banana,

starfruit

..

User Group

tomato

..

Here's the code I have so far...I'm a newbie at this, so I'm a bit stumped.

```
var playerBatch = new Array();

playerBatch["00"] =
[
{userName: "apple", bestScore: "10"}
{userName: "banana", bestScore: "20"}
{userName: "starfruit", bestScore: "20"}
{userName: "tomato", bestScore: "30"}
];


var batch = "00";

for (i=0; i < playerBatch[batch].length; i++) {
    if (playerBatch[batch][i].bestScore == "10") {
        document.write("User Group")
        document.write(playerBatch[batch][i].userName)
    }
};
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to tackle this, I'd be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: do you know what functions are?

Comment: Actually, yes.  I'm using one in my actual code.  I'm just posting a super simplified version of the code to figure out *what* to put in the function.  So no need to be rude.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** It looks like what you're missing in the example is the commas between the objects in `playerBatch["00"]`. That will scuttle the whole thing before you get into the sorting work.

In order to group multiple results, you need to cache/store all the matches (likely in an locally-scoped array) before invoking the `document.write()`.

… and if you want to list out all the groups by `bestScore`, you'll have to loop through the array to build a list (array) of possible `bestScore` values, *then* loop through that with something like the code you have already written.

That said, you will probably want to massage the (output) string(s) that you're writing into the document — to add space between "User Group" and the resulting match(es), control line-breaks, or wrap strings with semantic HTML. Depending on how complex your finished layout has to be, you might benefit from using a templating library like [Handelbars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or even [Nano (templates)](https://github.com/trix/nano).

```js
var playerBatch = new Array();

playerBatch["00"] = [{
  userName: "apple",
  bestScore: "10"
}, {
  userName: "banana",
  bestScore: "20"
}, {
  userName: "starfruit",
  bestScore: "20"
}, {
  userName: "tomato",
  bestScore: "30"
}];


var batch = "00",
    groupArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < playerBatch[batch].length; i++) {
  if (playerBatch[batch][i].bestScore == "20") {
    groupArray.push(playerBatch[batch][i].userName)
  }
};

if( groupArray.length ){
  document.write( "User Group: " );
  document.write( groupArray.join( ", " ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ito, this along with using UnderscoreJS's groupBy with my function did the trick!  I'm not sure how to officially 'resolve' this question so that you get credit for your help, but it looks like I'm all set.

```js
var playerBatch = new Array();

playerBatch["00"] = [{
  userName: "apple",
  bestScore: "10"
}, {
  userName: "banana",
  bestScore: "20"
}, {
  userName: "starfruit",
  bestScore: "20"
}, {
  userName: "tomato",
  bestScore: "30"
}];


var batch = "00",
    groupArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < playerBatch[batch].length; i++) {
  if (playerBatch[batch][i].bestScore == "20") {
    groupArray.push(playerBatch[batch][i].userName)
  }
};

if( groupArray.length ){
  document.write( "User Group: " );
  document.write( groupArray.join( ", " ) );
}
```